# It can't see my Queue: "Expected: 0, Actual: 1"

Tags: unit-test, queue

System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 0, Actual: 1
How can I fix it?

```
Group testGroup = new Group(Name = 'XXX', Type = 'Queue');
    insert testGroup;
    List<Obj__c> oList = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Obj__c WHERE OwnerId =: testGroup.Id];
    System.assertEquals(oList.size(), 1);
```

testGroup.Id is not null.

Comment: your Group insertion might have failed, add a assert before query to see if you have a group id.

Comment: I have group Id.

Comment: You haven't assigned any records to the ownership of the Queue. That query *should* return no results.

Comment: The first parameter in `assertEquals` is the expected value. Please stick to that to avoid future debugging headaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't inserted any records in to the queue yet, so 0 is the expected value. Instead, you need to follow the following steps: insert the Group, insert a [QueueSObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_queuesobject.htm), then insert at least one `Obj__c` record with that OwnerId. Please note that the the Group and QueueSObject must be created inside a System.runAs block, because they are considered Setup Objects.

Here's a demo from a unit test I wrote recently:

```
@isTest static void test() {
    Group g = new Group(Name='TestQueue',Type='Queue');
    System.runas(new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId())) {
        insert g;
        insert new QueueSobject(QueueId=g.id, SObjectType='Lead');
    }
    insert new lead(lastname='test',company='test');
    insert new lead(lastname='testqueue',company='testqueue',ownerid=g.Id);
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

`Obj__c` insert is missing, no records in it.

Need to insert obj__c with `ownerId` set as the `testGroup.Id`